# Moles/VS2010 SP1 Issue - Error 32, exit code -1002 building mstest with Moles 0.94.51023.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

**Update 6/20/2011**
I can only build the test project once or twice before getting this error. Moles is unusable for me until this is resolved. Deleting obj/bin and closing/reopening visual studio isn't practical.

**The Error**

Error   32  The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @C:\src\qp\mvc3\Solution\QP.Tests.Moles\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1002.   QP.Tests.Moles

**The Description**

Was trying to use moles with nunit but had trouble... so I created a new mstest project with a single test. The test built and I was able to debug into the SUT and verify HttpContext contained values expected. Subsequent attempts to build the test project fail with the above.

note: I am running resharper 6 EAP (i know, i know) but I have disabled it's mstest runner. besides, this is a build error.

**What I've Tried**

Have tried rebuild, clean and deleting obj/bin directories in the test project.

**The Code**

```
namespace QP.Tests.Moles
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            INewsService _newsService = new NewsService();
            BHttpContext context = BHttpContext.SetCurrent();
            BIPrincipal user = context.SetUser();
            BIIdentity identity = user.SetIdentity();
            identity.Name = "AMole";

            var newsItemViewModel = new NewsItemViewModel()
            {
                Headline = "some headline that passes validation",
                FullMessage = "some full message that passes validation",
                ProviderListItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Selected = false,
                            Text = "some text",
                            Value = "some value"
                        }
                }

            };
            _newsService.UpdateNewsItem(newsItemViewModel, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you post your own answer to this question, and mark it as the accepted answer.  Good issue to post!

Comment: yeah, but SO won't let you answer your own questions ;)  I have updated the issue as the error occurs almost every time I build the test project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing and re-opening VisualStudio is a workaround for this issue.