# How do you remove Moles from a project? (Moles 0.94.51023.0 / VS2010 SP1)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moles, pex

**The Problem**

Not only can I not use Moles [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381196/moles-vs2010-sp1-issue-error-32-exit-code-1002-building-mstest-with-moles-0-9) I can't get rid of them either (much like my backyard). I'm sure I'm missing something [not] obvious [to me]. I see I'm not the only person having [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504741/why-does-moles-keep-getting-readded-to-my-project).

**The Symptom**

After removing the moles config file (in the project dir I think, don't remember the name) and removing references to the mscorlib moles/behaviors I rebuild and the references are added back. I also removed the MolesAssemblies directory though a link below says that bug was fixed.

**Misc links**

I found an [older reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/2c108a14-9860-4c2e-a53d-a16ece4545ab) to removing the MolesAssemblies directory (which I tried) but that was fixed a long time ago.

I also found this detailed suggestion for [removing moles at home](http://arnolddavies.blogs.experienceproject.com/625126.html), but it didn't work either ;)

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504741/why-does-moles-keep-getting-readded-to-my-project Note: the "Moled Assemblies" folder was only on the file system and not in my VS solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Moles keep getting readded to my project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504741/why-does-moles-keep-getting-readded-to-my-project)

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete any mention of moles from the project directory, including from obj.